# Is it feasible to model level of human effort (i.e., person-seconds) in an activity diagram with Cameo Systems Modeler?

Tags: uml, simulation, activity-diagram, sysml, magic-draw

I am using Cameo Systems Modeler and would like to simulate human activities and the levels of effort for each action.

I have tried using input and output pins, but those seem to make no sense for my purpose. I am not sure whether this is a UML function vs. a SysML one, so I tagged both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The time needed for the execution is not an input or output. It is a property of the execution. You can define constraints for these properties. In your case, you can use duration constraints.

[image]

The cameo simulation engine will use these times for the simulation.

Defining a Person-Second would be interesting for the simulation, when you also define the number of Persons working on it. As far as I see, there is no easy solution to make the simulation engine aware of it. If you create your own simulation enviroment, then you could use the attributes of the Activity itself. An Activity is a special kind of Class and therefore can have attributes.

Comment: It is also possible to capture the "simtime" variable per Monte Carlo run, but so far the only way I have found is to apply the duration constraints not to the actions describing the elements of activity, but to opaque code blocks renaming the `simtime` variable to something which can then be passed via object flows. I need to do Monte Carlo method because there are decision points in the activity diagrams with probabilities for each fork adding to 1.

Comment: It seems you found a way to make something useful with this. However, passing the `simtime` as an object flow looks to me like a workaround. It doesn't model what is really happennig, since the execution time is a property of the execution, not an output. I'm always sceptical, if something is used for purposes that are not intended. Of course, if it solves your problem, it might be Ok.

Comment: I have to save the simtime to an external file using an opaque action.